# Order of function signature, call and definition

Tags: c++, function

I want to ask order of function signature, call and definition

like, which one would the computer look first, second and third

So:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void max(void);
void min(void);

int main() {

max();

min();

return;
}

void max() {

return;
}

void min() {

return;
}
```

So this is what I think,

the computer will go to main and look at the function call, then it will look at the

function signature, and at the last, it will look at the definition.

It is right?

Thank

Comment: Are you asking about what the computer does during compilation or during runtime?

Comment: It'll probably get rid of all traces of the functions completely.

Comment: I am asking during the runtime, which thing(signature, call and definition) do the computer look first and second...

Comment: @RexRau, In that case, check out the produced assembly. With optimizations on, though, there's a fair chance of neither of those functions existing because they're completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, the compiler converts the program into machine code (via several intermediate steps). Here is the dissassembly of the machine code for `main()` when compiled on Visual Studio 2012 in debug mode on Windows 8:

```
int main() {
00C24400  push        ebp                         # Setup stack frame
00C24401  mov         ebp,esp  
00C24403  sub         esp,0C0h  
00C24409  push        ebx  
00C2440A  push        esi  
00C2440B  push        edi  
00C2440C  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]              # Fill with guard bytes
00C24412  mov         ecx,30h                     
00C24417  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00C2441C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  

max();
00C2441E  call        max (0C21302h)              # Call max  

min();
00C24423  call        min (0C2126Ch)              # Call min

return 0;
00C24428  xor         eax,eax  
}
00C2442A  pop         edi                         # Restore stack frame    
00C2442B  pop         esi  
00C2442C  pop         ebx  
00C2442D  add         esp,0C0h  
00C24433  cmp         ebp,esp  
}
00C24435  call        __RTC_CheckEsp (0C212D5h)   # Check for memory corruption
00C2443A  mov         esp,ebp  
00C2443C  pop         ebp  
00C2443D  ret
```

The exact details will vary from compiler to compiler and operating system to operating system. If min() or max() had arguments or return values, they would be passed as appropriate for the architecture. The key point is that the compiler has already worked out what the arguments and return values are and created machine code that just passes or accepts them.

You can learn more details if you wish to help with debugging or to do low level calls but be aware that the machine code emitted can be highly variable. For example, here is the same code compiled on the same system in release mode (i.e. with optimizations on):

```
return 0;
01151270  xor         eax,eax  
}
01151272  ret
```

As you can see, it has detected that `min()` and `max()` do nothing and removed them completely. Since there is now no stack frame to setup and restore, that is gone, leaving a single instruction to set eax to 0 then returning (since the return value is in the eax register).

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with assembly, but I think the release one's "noop" is just making eax 0 by XORing it with itself, followed by a ret instruction to return from the program with that value of 0.

Comment: @chris That is correct. I have explained it further in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> It is right?

No.

You need to understand the difference between function declarations and function definitions, the difference between compilation, linking, and execution, and the difference between non-virtual and virtual functions.

**Function declarations**
This is a function declaration: `void max(void);`. It doesn't tell the compiler anything about what the function does. What it does is to tell the compiler how to call the function and how to interpret the result. When the compiler is compiling the body of some function, call it function A, the compiler doesn't need to know what other functions do. All it needs to know is what to do with the functions that function A calls. The compiler might generate code in assembly or some intermediate language that corresponds to your C++ function calls. Or it might reject your C++ code because your code doesn't make sense.

Determining whether your code makes sense is another key purpose of those function declarations. This is particularly important in C++ where multiple functions can have the same name. How would the compiler know which of the half dozen or so `max` functions to call if it didn't know about those functions? When your C++ code calls some function, the compiler must find one best match (possibly involving type conversions) with one of those function declarations. Your code doesn't make sense if the compiler can't find a match at all, or if it finds more than one match but can't distinguish one as the best match.

When the compiler does find a best match, the generated code will be in the form of a call to an undefined external reference to that function. Where that function lives is not the job of the compiler.

**Function definitions**
That `void max(void)` was a function declaration. The corresponding `void max() {...}` is the *definition* of that function. When the compiler is processing `void max() {...}` it doesn't have to worry about what other functions have called it. It just has to worry about processing `void max() {...}` . The body of this function becomes assembly or intermediate language code that is inserted into some compiled object file. The compiler marks the address of the entry point to this generated code is marked as such.

**Compilation versus linking**
So far I've talked about what the compiler does. It generates chunks of low-level code that correspond to your C++ code. That generated code is not ready for prime time because of those external references. Resolving those undefined external references is the job of the linker. The linker is what builds your executable from multiple object files, multiple libraries. It keeps track of where it has put those chunks of code in the executable. What about those undefined external references? If the linker has already placed that reference in the executable, the linker simply fills in the placeholder for that reference. If the linker hasn't come across the definition for that reference, it puts the reference and the placeholder onto a list of still-unresolved references. Every time the linker adds a chunk of code to the executable, it checks that list to see if it can fix any of those still-unresolved references. At the end, you will either have all references resolved or you will still have some outstanding ones. The latter is an error. The former means that you have an executable.

**Execution**
When your code runs, those function calls are really just some stack management wrapped around the machine language equivalent of that evil `goto` statement. There's no examining your function declarations; those don't even exist by the time the code is executed. Return? That's a `goto` also.

**Non-virtual versus virtual functions**
What I said above pertains to non-virtual functions. Run-time dispatching does occur for virtual functions. That run-time dispatching has nothing to do with examining function declarations. Those virtual functions are perhaps an issue for a different question.

**One last thing:**
Get out of the habit of `using namespace std;` Think of it as akin to smoking. It's a bad habit.